# Flat File to Netezza Load in SSIS

Tags: ssis, netezza

Any fastest way where I can load a pipe delimited flat file to Netezza DAtabase through SSIS? Currently it is take one minute to load 60 MB of data.

Comment: Can you tell us more about your SSIS job? Are you using the Netezza OLE-DB driver as the target?

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to load a pipe-delimited file would be to pass the file to nzload (the bulk loader provided with the netezza client utilities) using something like a script component.

If you already have an existing SSIS package that you simply want to alter, your performance will be best when you use the Netezza OLE-DB provider as the destination, and you should set the following properties:

```
AccessMode = OpenRowSet With FastLoad
FastLoadMaxInsertCommitSize = 0
```

It may be the case that you won't see these directly in the destination edit panel. You will probably have to access these through the properties tab.

Answer (score 0):

use NZLOAD utility or insert the data from flat file(considering as external table) and load data from external table to netezza table.